# How do you replace one syntax token with multiple ones?

Tags: roslyn

I've written an analyzer to force a library to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of blocking a thread with .Result / .Wait()

After several hours and attempts to find a way to generate a syntaxtree which covers all my test cases i attempted to use the ReplaceToken method.

#### SyntaxNodeExtensions.cs

```cs
public static TRoot ReplaceToken<TRoot>(this TRoot root, SyntaxToken tokenInList, IEnumerable<SyntaxToken> newTokens) where TRoot : SyntaxNode
{
  return (TRoot) root.ReplaceTokenInListCore(tokenInList, newTokens);
}
```

seemed like the perfect method - however i never got it working using this method.

I ended up doing it this way (which to me, seems rather lazy):

#### My working codefix

```cs
private async Task<Document> ReplaceWithGetAwaiterGetResultAsync(Document document, IdentifierNameSyntax declaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var source = await document.GetTextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if(declaration.Identifier.ValueText == "Result")
        return document.WithText(source.Replace(declaration.Span, "GetAwaiter().GetResult()"));
    if(declaration.Identifier.ValueText == "Wait")
        return document.WithText(source.Replace(new TextSpan(declaration.SpanStart, 6), "GetAwaiter().GetResult()"));

    return document;
}
```

Does anyone know a better way of how i could have turned something like

```cs
Task.Run(() => 42).Result
```

into

```cs
Task.Run(() => 42).GetAwaiter.GetResult()
```

?

E.g. a version of this:

```cs
var tokens = SyntaxFactory.ParseTokens("GetAwaiter().GetResult()");
var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
var replaced = root.ReplaceToken(declaration.Identifier, tokens);

return document.WithSyntaxRoot(replaced.WithAdditionalAnnotations());
```

which does not crash.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you faced when implementing your solution was that you tried to replace tokens. The access of the Result Property is however not a Token but a [SyntaxNode](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/learn-roslyn-now-part-3-syntax-nodes-and-syntax-tokens/).

The structure of your code consists of a MemberAccessExpression (Task.Run().Result) containing a MethodInvocationExpression (Task.Run()).

What you're trying to achieve is to remove the MemberAccessExpression, create a new MethodInvocationExpression (invocating GetAwaiter()) and insert the original InvocationExpression into your new Expression in order to call GetAwaiter() on the original expression.

Then you need to create *another* Incovation Expression to call GetResult().

To do this you need to create a new node like this and replace the old node using the SyntaxRoot:

```c#
private async Task<Document> ReplaceWithAwaiter(Document document, 
        IdentifierNameSyntax nameSyntax, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var memberAccess = nameSyntax.Ancestors().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>()
        .First();
    // Create .GetAwaiter()
    var invocationOfAwaiter = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(
        SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
        memberAccess.Expression, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("GetAwaiter")));
    // Create .GetResult()
    var invocationOfGetResult = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(
        SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
        invocationOfAwaiter, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("GetResult")));
    // Replace .Result by .GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
    syntaxRoot = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(memberAccess, invocationOfGetResult);
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(syntaxRoot);
}
```

For .Wait() the code is a bit different, but the same principle applies. In this case you want to replace an InvocationExpression instead of a MemberAccessExpression however.

```c#
private async Task<Document> ReplaceWithAwaiterForWait(Document document, 
        IdentifierNameSyntax nameSyntax, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the Invocation Task.Run().Wait()
    var invocationOfWait = nameSyntax.Ancestors().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
        .First();
    // Get the Access for Task.Run().Wait
    var memberAccessOfWait = (MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)invocationOfWait.Expression;
    // Get the Invocation Task.Run()
    var invocationOfTaskRun = memberAccessOfWait.Expression;
    // Create new Expressions
    var invocationOfAwaiter = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(
        SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
        invocationOfTaskRun, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("GetAwaiter")));
    var invocationOfGetResult = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(
        SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
        invocationOfAwaiter, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("GetResult")));
    var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
    // Replace the old expression
    syntaxRoot = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(invocationOfWait, invocationOfGetResult);
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(syntaxRoot);
}
```

If you don't wont to work with the generation of individual nodes you could also just use SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression() to generate a new expression and replace the old one:

```c#
private async Task<Document> ReplaceWithAwaiterWithParse(Document document, 
                    IdentifierNameSyntax nameSyntax, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var invocationOfWait = nameSyntax.Ancestors().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
                    .First();
    var memberAccessOfWait = (MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)invocationOfWait.Expression;
    var invocationOfBoth = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(
                    memberAccessOfWait.Expression.ToFullString() 
                    + ".GetAwaiter().GetResult()");
    var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
    syntaxRoot = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(invocationOfWait, invocationOfBoth);
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(syntaxRoot);
}
```

While this solution is a little shorter and more concise you would not be working on a string instead of the SyntaxTree which could create all kinds of issues. Furthermore the performance is a bit worse than using the SyntaxFactory to create individual objects. However you do not have to create every part of the invocation yourself.

Comment: actually the result of declaration.Identifier is a token with Wait/Result. The reason i dislike solving it with nodes here is because the syntax it is connected with can make rewriting more difficult. However i'll play with your answer and upvote accordingly later. thanks

Comment: Nice solution. I will leave this answer open though, since i would really love to know still how to replace one token with multiple ones as ReplaceToken's method signature method suggests (a solution using that + SyntaxFactory.ParseTokens("GetAwaiter().GetResult()") should be way more convenient in terms of solution simplicity. I've tested your answer though and it resolved all my test cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did append another solution which uses SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression. It's still rather verbose as you'd have to find the original Invocation as well as the expression calling .Wait() or .Result, however the parsing itself can be done without creating individual SyntaxNodes. However I would of course also be interested if someone else knows a more elegant solution.

Comment: Your third code chunk fails for: var task = new Task<int>(() => 42); task.Result; - var rTyped6 = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>(() => { return Task.Run(() => 42).Result; }).Result; That is why i was looking for a way to replace one token with multiple, to not have to deal with a surrounding node tree and instead just patch it up using tokens only which require no knowledge of surrounding nodes. Unfortunately so far mine still seems like it's the easiest to comprehend. Meh :/